# Wordpress wp_new_user_notification() is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created page template where I am creating new user and want to send email to new user via this function "wp_new_user_notification()". It's not giving me any response.

Here is my code:

```
if (null == username_exists($user_email)) {
     include_once (home_url().'/wp-includes/pluggable.php');
     // Generate the password and create the user
     $password = wp_generate_password(12, false);
     $user_id = wp_create_user($user_email, $password, $user_email);

     // Email the user
     wp_new_user_notification($user_id);
 } // end if
```

Comment: Are you working in theme functions.php file?

Comment: No i have page template in theme folder

Comment: No need to include this file include_once (home_url().'/wp-includes/pluggable.php'); in theme

Comment: It doesn't effect the process.I removed it, but still above functions doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: can you post your full code with hook?

Comment: There is no hook, i am using this code directly inside my page template.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this function like this :

```
wp_new_user_notification( $user_id,'','user' );
```